# Windows Batch File: Output filename without extension

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a windows batch file which takes a file, runs it through a compiler to minify the file, then spits it back out.  My question is, how can I rename the file like so:

I want it to go from `script.js` to `script.min.js`

I am using the below script:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
FOR %%c in (C:\source\*.*) DO java -jar ./Compiler/compiler.jar %%c --js_output_file %%c.min.js
ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

When I use the script, it outputs the file with a filename of `script.js.min.js` so I was hoping that I could just cut out the `.js` first, and then append the .min.js afterward.

**UPDATE:**

If there is a way to output the name of the file then append `.min.js` I think I would prefer that.

Comment: Your "Unix script" appears to be a Windows batch file. What version or Unix or Linux are you on? Or are you?

Comment: @NedNowotny Yep.  Don't know much about unix or batch files.  It looks like it's a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR %%c in (C:\source\*.*) DO java -jar ./Compiler/compiler.jar %%c --js_output_file %%~dpnc.min.js
```

The ~dpn selects just the drive,path,name portions and omits the extension (x)