# How to use mogrify (ImageMagick) to convert from NEF to *.jpg and retain EXIF data?

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, exif, exiftool, mogrify

I'm converting about 9000 photos from .NEF to .jpg.

- I'd like to retain all EXIF data, most importantly Date and time created, Latidude and Longitude.
- I'd like the JPGs to be at the highest possible quality.

I've just gotten started using ImageMagick from the command line. I also have *Exiftool* installed. I'm using the `mogrify` command because it handles batches nicely.

When I run

```
mogrify -format jpg *.NEF
```

All of my .NEF files are successfully converted to JPGs, but **all EXIF data are lost**.

I've searched around quite a bit to try and find a solution to this and it seems like I may have to install ufraw, but if possible I'd like a solution that uses software I already have - *ImageMagick* and *Exiftool*.

Thanks in advance for any advice you have about how to do this.

**Update:**

- The images I converted using mogrify are slightly smaller (~ 1-2 MB) than those output by my colleague using picasa to convert NEF to JPG. But when I specify `-quality 100` in ImageMagick the image sizes gain about 45 MB! Why?
- The code `exiftool -tagsfromfile %d%f.NEF -ext jpg -overwrite_original .` adds the exif information to the JPGs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think twice before doing this - you really are discarding a lot of information - and if you don't want it, why not shoot JPEG instead of RAW in the first place?

FWIW, you can use ImageMagick to get the JPEG:

```
convert somefile.NEF somefile.jpg
```

Then you can copy the tags across from the original to the file newly created by ImageMagick:

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile somefile.NEF -all:all somefile.jpg
```

---

If you have thousands of images, and are on macOS or a decent Linux/Unix-based OS, I would recommend **GNU Parallel** like this and it will keep busy all those lovely cores that you paid Intel so dearly for:

```
parallel --dry-run 'convert {} {.}.jpg; exiftool -tagsfromfile {} -all:all {.}.jpg' ::: *nef
```

**Sample Output**

```
convert a.nef a.jpg; exiftool -tagsfromfile a.nef -all:all a.jpg
convert b.nef b.jpg; exiftool -tagsfromfile b.nef -all:all b.jpg
```

and if that looks good remove the `--dry-run` so it actually runs the command.

---

If you are on Windows, you will have to do some ad-hoc jiggery-pokery to get it done in any reasonable time frame. You can use the `mogrify` command and get all the conversions done to JPEG and then do all the `exiftool` re-embedding of the EXIF data later. If your files are named with some sort of system with incrementing numbers, you can start two or three copies of `mogrify` in parallel - say one doing files whose names end in [0-4] and another one doing files whose names end in [5-9]. I don't speak Windows, but that would probably look like these two commands each running in its own Command Prompt:

```
mogrify -format jpg *0.NEF *1.NEF *2.NEF *3.NEF *4.NEF

mogrify -format jpg *5.NEF *6.NEF *7.NEF *8.NEF *9.NEF
```

Then you would do the `exiftool` stuff when they had all finished but you would have to use a FOR loop like [this](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```
FOR %%G IN (*.NEF) DO (
   exiftool -tagsfromfile %%G -all:all %%~dpnG.jpg
)
```

The `%%~dpnG` part is a guess based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21690417/2836621).

Comment: Thanks Mark, appreciate it. Your example looks like it's for one photo - how would I batch this for 9000?  Just an explanatory note: we take the photos in RAW to have the maximum amount of information in case we need them later. We are putting all photos into a mosaic, and our mosaic program doesn't take NEFs - the jpgs have worked fine in the past. I'm part of a larger research team, and I don't have control over what format the photos are taken in ;)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Using Windows 7. I do have 40 gigs of RAM but I'd like to be able to save maybe 4 gigs for other work today? I can always let it run overnight.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Mark Setchell! But I'm looking for a Windows solution... it sounds like that code won't run on my Windows computer?

Comment: Great! Thanks for that tip for processing mogrify in parallel. I've updated my question as well to a solution that doesn't create annoying backup jpgs.